# Is it possible to configure domain joined computers via GP or otherwise to automatically register for the free Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-10

Is it possible to configure domain joined computers via GP or otherwise to automatically register for the free Windows 10 upgrade, but also prevent the upgrade from automatically installing?

In other words, I would like to take advantage of the free upgrade, but roll it out in a controlled manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can get the windows 10 upgrade for free, however you will need to manually go to each PC and start the upgrade process.

Source: https://redmondmag.com/articles/2015/06/03/windows-10-upgrade-possibilities.aspx